# Weird string formatting with 2 vs 4 decimal places in currency field

Tags: string-formatting, abap, currency

I have the following piece of code. I want to format numbers with string templates. One variable has 2 decimal places, the other 4 decimal places but they represent the same number 50000 (fifty thousand).

The first number is correctly formatted (German representation) `50.000,00`, the other one however is formatted as 5 million `5.000.000,00`!

```
DATA: lv_p2 TYPE p LENGTH 9 DECIMALS 2,
      lv_p4 TYPE p LENGTH 14 DECIMALS 4.

START-OF-SELECTION.
  lv_p2 = '50000'.
  lv_p4 = lv_p2.

SET COUNTRY 'DE'.
"This is correctly formatted as 50.000,00
WRITE |{ lv_p2 NUMBER = ENVIRONMENT CURRENCY = 'EUR' }|.

"This is on the other hand interpreted as five million! 5.000.000,00
WRITE |{ lv_p4 NUMBER = ENVIRONMENT CURRENCY = 'EUR' }|.
```

Is this documented somewhere? What am I doing wrong here?

EDIT:

It looks like the problem is with the addition `CURRENCY`. If I don't use it, then the number is correctly formatted.

```
WRITE |{ lv_p4 NUMBER = ENVIRONMENT }|.
```

or `WRITE |{ lv_p4 NUMBER = ENVIRONMENT DECIMALS = 2 }|`.

Anyway looks like some kind of a bug.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe this behaviour is documented.

[ABAP Documentation - WRITE, format_options - CURRENCY cur](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_latest_index_htm/latest/en-us/index.htm?file=abapwrite_to_options.htm#!ABAP_ADDITION_6@6@)

When CURRENCY is added:

> "For data objects of type p, the decimal places determined by the
> definition of the data type are ignored completely. Independently of
> the actual value and without rounding, decimal separators and
> thousands separators are inserted between the digits in the places
> determined by cur."

Shortly: if CURRENCY is added (by WRITE), the number of decimal places is determined by the currency (in this case EUR has 2 decimal places), so the value 50.000,0000 will be 5.000.000,00. Same length (9 digits) only the number of decimals will be different.

Comment: so we should convert into proper decimal format before using CURRENCY addition? what is the proper way?

Comment: SAP always stores the posting amounts in the database with two decimals (regardless of the number of decimal places of the currency - 2 decimal places are standard, but there are currencies without any decimal place), so I follow this in my ABAP programs as well, declare currency fields with two decimals.